# How to get matched string file pointer position using Shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have to read a txt file where it has html content. match the string patten, if it matches then, get all the content of next line in the text file.

Confused what shell commands to be used. Found few sample codes using like EXEC, CAT..but was not able to get my expected output.

this is the content inside webData.txt

```
<li id="rowForcustomfield_10003" class="item">
    <div class="wrap">
        <strong title="Name" class="name">Name:</strong>
        <div id="customfield_10003-val" class="value type-cascadingselect" data-fieldtype=
        "cascadingselect" data-fieldtypecompletekey="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.
        customfieldtypes:cascadingselect">  JAMES   - WELLIS </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

if string "Name" is matched then i need to save "JAMES  - WELLIS"

Few name in text file also appear as below with mutiple spaces and new line.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <strong title="Architecture/Derivate" class="name">Name:</strong>
    <div id="customfield_10003-val" class="value type-cascadingselect" data-fieldtype="cascadingselect" data-fieldtypecompletekey="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:cascadingselect">
                                GREG
     R GEORGE

                    </div>
</div>
```

here is a sample code i've found

```
  do
    if [[ $(grep ">Name:"  $line) ]];
    then
     echo "$line + 1"    # get next line data from webData.txt
    fi
  done < webData.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try smth simple like the below, it will extract all names in a file named `output.txt`

```
 while read line 
 do  
    [[ "$line" == *"Name"* ]] && continue 
    echo "$line"| cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1 >> output.txt 
 done < <(grep -A1 'Name' webData.txt)
```

EDIT

For shells that do not allow process substitution :

```
grep -A1 'Name' webData.txt | while read line
 do
    [[ "$line" == *"Name"* ]] && continue
    echo "$line"| cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1 >> output1.txt
 done
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but i'm getting syntax error at line                            ```done < <(grep -A1 'Name' webData.txt) ```

Comment: below is the error mesaage i get `syntax error near unexpected token `<'`

Comment: please make sure you use bash to invoke your script, eg try to run it with `bash yourscript.sh`  -- see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168482/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token) to understand why

Comment: can this piece of code be made comptible to be executed as `sh yourscript.sh`

Comment: In the new updated code if string "Name" is matched, then it will save "JAMES - WELLIS". But there are cases in input file were name are stored as `                                       GREG         -              GORGE            `. It has multiple spaces, and ouput field is empty